# Why do I get a list from an integral over a region when my integrand is scalar?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, regions

In *Mathematica* 13.2.1.0 on Windows 10, this integral gives an unexpected result:

```
Integrate[EuclideanDistance[x, {2, 0}], x ∈ Circle[]]/ RegionMeasure[Circle[]]
```

```
{0, (1/(2 \[Pi]))
 Integrate[Sqrt[
  Abs[-2 + Sin[Region`RegionIntegrateDump`t]]^2 + 
   Abs[Sin[Region`RegionIntegrateDump`t]]^2], {Region`RegionIntegrateDump`t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  GenerateConditions -> False, Assumptions -> True]}
```

The presence of `` Region`RegionIntegrateDump`t `` suggests a bug somewhere.
But more importantly, I was expecting a scalar, not a list.

If we try numerically we also get a list, which seems wrong:

```
NIntegrate[EuclideanDistance[x, {2, 0}], x ∈ Circle[]]/RegionMeasure[Circle[]]
(* {2.13996, 2.13996} *)
```

It seems *Mathematica* doesn't know that certain integrands are scalar, e.g:
`NIntegrate[Max[x], x ∈ Circle[]]` gives `{0,0}` while  `NIntegrate[Total[x], x ∈ Circle[]]` gives a scalar `-1.11022*10^-15` and some convergence warnings.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in `Integrate`. If you look at `EuclideanDistance[x, {2, 0}]`, it evaluates to `Sqrt[Abs[-2 + x]^2 + Abs[x]^2]` which will then return a list if `x` is a list. `Integrate[EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {2, 0}], {x, y} ∈ Circle[]]` works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your integrand is not a scalar. `EuclideanDistance[u, v]` is equivalent to `Norm[u - v]`. Therefore, `EuclideanDistance[x, {2, 0}]` is equivalent to `Norm[{x - 2, x}]`. When `x` is a list, this will thread and produce a list of results.

You can either manually specify all coordinates:

```
Integrate[EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {2, 0}], {x, y} ∈ Circle[]]
(* 4 EllipticE[-8] *)
```

or prevent premature evalution of `EuclideanDistance`:

```
f[x_?VectorQ] := EuclideanDistance[x, {2, 0}]
Integrate[f[x], x ∈ Circle[]]
(* 4 EllipticE[-8] *)
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to have to list out components so the second form with `VectorQ` is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, I've been able to use this:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[(Indexed[x, 1] - 0)^2 + (Indexed[x, 2] - 2)^2], 
  x ∈ Circle[]]/RegionMeasure[Circle[]]
```

```
(EllipticE[π/4, -8] + EllipticE[(3 π)/4, -8])/π
(* approx 2.12709 *)
```

This result looks like it agrees with random experiment:

```
SeedRandom[1];
Mean[EuclideanDistance[#, {0, 2}] & /@ RandomPoint[Circle[], 100000]]
(* 2.12668 *)
```